# Can I check for a certain set of letters inside inputted letters and numbers? (C#)

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to create a fake shell program in C#, but I need to know how to display two different messages depending on whether or not the user puts 'cd' infront of their "command".

Here's a part of my code:

```
/* C:\Users dir */
users:

Console.Write("C://Users>");
string userValueFromUsers;
userValueFromUsers = Console.ReadLine();
if (userValueFromUsers.Equals("exit"))
{
    goto end;
}
else if (userValueFromUsers.Equals(""))
{
    goto users;
}
else if (userValueFromUsers.Equals("cd.."))
{
    goto users;
}
else if (userValueFromUsers.Equals("cd " + random text));
{
    Console.WriteLine("The system cannot find the path specified.");
}
else if (userValueFromUsers.Equals("cd.."))
{
    goto c;
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("'" + userValueFromUsers + "' is not recognised as an internal or external command,"); Console.WriteLine("operable program or batch file.\n")
goto users;
```

My problem is at the line that reads "if (userValueFromUsers.Equals("cd " + random text"));", with 'random text' being my current placeholder for 'anything the user says.'

To clarify, c, start, end and users are all just parts of my code, c being the C:\ directory, start being the start and end being how you exit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Independently from your question, the code line you pointed out is not compilable: `else if (userValueFromUsers.Equals("cd " + random text"));`. Also, your last code after `else` seems wrong. Are you missing `{` and `}` brackets?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are asking, but your code seems to have some logical errors. Maybe they are already part of your problem? Try this here. Does it work now?

Also, you test twice for "cd..". The second test is never executed. I removed it from the source code.

```
/* C:\Users dir */
users:

Console.Write("C://Users>");
string userValueFromUsers;
userValueFromUsers = Console.ReadLine();
if (userValue.Equals("exit"))
{
    goto end;
}
else if (userValueFromUsers.Equals(""))
{
    goto users;
}
else if (userValueFromUsers.Equals("cd.."))
{
    goto users;
}
else if (userValueFromUsers.Equals("cd " + "random text"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("The system cannot find the path specified.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("'" + userValueFromUsers + "' is not recognised as an internal or external command,");
    Console.WriteLine("operable program or batch file.\n");
    goto users;
}
```